# nginx redirecting to different SSL environment (though not in Chrome Private Browsing mode): why?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two environments of the same website on two different local servers.

One is https://dev.example.com, the other is https://test.example.com

I've been doing lots of work in the dev environment, and all is well.  But having now just created the test environment, I'm finding that when I go to https://test.example.com - it is redirecting me to https://dev.example.com before showing the Secure notification next to the address bar.

But if I launch Private Browsing mode in Chrome, this doesn't happen (it correctly serves up the test environment.)

I have checked the nginx configuration and there is no mistake regarding redirection - in fact, there is nothing in the configuration for the test environment that even mentions dev.example.com (nginx or the code for the iste itself) - so it must be Chrome caching something.

I have cleared all cookies that existed for dev.example.com but the redirection is still happening.

The two sites use the same wildcard ssl certificate btw.

Flummoxed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know why the redirect was happening in the first place - but I have found how to resolve the problem:

In Chrome:

- Open dev tools (f12)
- In dev tools settings, tick "Disable cache"
- Visit https://test.example.com
- Re-enable the cache